# Blank space bottom of text when using font family

Tags: ios, css, react-native, fonts

I face an issue when I apply font family for my `Text` component as the image below

[image]

As you can see, my text cannot align center itself (red area is my default `Text` component, without any margin or padding).

I think this issue comes from my font (`TradeGothicLTStd-BdCn2`) because when I change the font, I don't see this issue anymore.

Here is my style for this component

```
 dropdownCurrentText: {
    fontFamily: Fonts.type.TradeGothicLTStdBold,
    fontSize: 14,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: Colors.black,
    letterSpacing: 0.2
  },
```

Does any suggestion to resolve this within keeping above font? any response would be appreciated.

P.S It's not happening on Android platform, only iOS

Comment: Have you looked at this prop: [includeFontPadding](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text). Setting it to `false` may work for you. Though it only works on Android

Comment: Have you tried playing with the line-height already?

Comment: @04FS thank you, I tried, but no hope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I find out the solution for my issue, thank for another answer.

That is using Font Tool for XCode, you guys can read this article for more detail https://medium.com/@martin_adamko/consistent-font-line-height-rendering-42068cc2957d

Comment: Thank you so mutch !!! i'v been wondering for month why my text got extra space and this answers solve my issue !!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to have to play with margin/padding values, you can define the text box as an inline-block element, give it a relative position and adjust the top/bottom value(s) accordingly to center it as you wish:

```css
div {
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

span {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>SELECT</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your response, I will try it and come back later

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this property to particular element :  `vertical-align: middle`